# Are multiple TCP connections a viable alternative to UDP? (WebSockets)

Tags: javascript, html, tcp, udp, websocket

I'm investigating WebSockets as a means of running an online game where there are multiple players on-screen and position updates for all are streamed to each client.

Unfortunately WebSockets are TCP only, so if there is congestion in the pipes, the stream will suffer.

My idea was to mitigate this as far as possible by making multiple WebSocket connections from the client (Same server, multiple ports?) and have the server stream updates to these connections in a round-robin manner.

If one stream is congested then the next update might make it through on another connection allowing the client to catch-up. Out-of-order stale updates are discarded.

Is this a viable solution? Am I talking networking nonsense? Or will it likely be a small mitigation for far too much engineering effort?

Comment: It sounds like a lot of effort for little to no benefit, but since there don't seem to be any benchmarks for this sort of thing, I guess I can't say for sure.

Comment: This question might be a better fit for gamedev.stackexchange.com